# Amazon SDK is causing Invalid IL Code Exception - Any idea what's causing this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've combed the internet. Nothing anywhere mentions IL Code exceptions with Amazon SDK, yet I'm getting them.

I am getting this completely wacked out Exception that says something about "Invalid IL code" and hash garbage.  I tried this on Framework 4.6.1, 4.5.2, and even Core. Its the same on all of them.

Target machine: Ubuntu 16.04 / mono.

**I get the same error trying to establish Credentials as I do when trying to create an ec2Client.**

**First,** I followed the Amazon Documentation to get credentials like this:

```
CredentialProfileStoreChain chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain("/home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials");
AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
chain.TryGetAWSCredentials("default", out awsCredentials))
```

Which gives me this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.SharedCredentialsFile' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<T_REF>:.ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<T_REF>): method body is empty.

  at Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.SharedCredentialsFile..cctor () <0x407090c0 + 0x0006a> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain.TryGetProfile (System.String profileName, Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfile& profile) <0x40708f30 + 0x000ce>...
```

**Secondly,** since the problem was happening in TryGetProfile, which is being called from TryGetAWSCredentials(), I removed the previous Credentials lookup creation code completely.  Then I hardcoded MyKeyID and MySecretKey direction into a new AmazonEC2Client function call like this:

```
ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client("{MYKEYID}", "{MYSECRETKEY}");
```

And then I get this exception:

```
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<T_REF>:.ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<T_REF>): method body is empty.

  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer..cctor () <0x40d5b830 + 0x000b2> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Client.CreateSigner () <0x40d5b7b0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor (Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials credentials, Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig config) <0x40d526d0 + 0x00142> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor (System.String awsAccessKeyId, System.String awsSecretAccessKey, Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig config) <0x40d52350 + 0x00067> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Client..ctor (System.String awsAccessKeyId, System.String awsSecretAccessKey, Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Config clientConfig) <0x40d52310 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Client..ctor (System.String awsAccessKeyId, System.String awsSecretAccessKey) <0x40d4ec00 + 0x0005d> in <filename unknown>:0
```

**RECAP: I made *two completely different* function calls to the Amazon SDK and both are giving me this common error:**

*Invalid IL code in System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<T_REF>:.ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1): method body is empty.*

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

*SIDE NOTE:  As a side note, for some bizarre reason, I was getting missing System.XML.Linq and missing System.Core errors unless I specifically copied them from Microsoft's default location to my bin folder. They aren't getting put there automatically when I do a build. Am I just completely using the SDK wrong somehow???*

Edited by: JamesHoux on Jul 20, 2018 2:43 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. "Invalid IL Code" literally means just that: Bad code that can't be executed

Invalid IL Code when running on Mono typically means either:

1) Your version of Mono needs to be updated

2) The library or program you're using/running doesn't work with Mono (or your version of Mono).

The server we were testing on had an old version of Mono because we mistakenly relied on Ubuntu repositories to install Mono instead of getting the latest official release from the Mono project website.  Updating Mono fixed the problem.  No more IL Code error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with "/home/ubuntu/aws_credentials". This file does not exist on your system.

This should be "/home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials"

Note change the part "/home/ubuntu" if your user name is different than "ubuntu".

Follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) and verify that your credentials are created correctly.

Note you can also have the system find the credential file (from the default locations) this way:

```
var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
```

Comment: Wow. Why does the CredentialProfileStoreChain throw such a nasty looking error when the problem is as simple as a missing file? You would think that the file open command would throw a typical error which Amazon's API should intercept and throw it's own exception giving you something more meaningful than this mess.

Comment: I am a c++ veteran. I just hate these stack dumps. Another of my favorite languages, Python does the same thing.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I'm pretty sure wrong file is not the problem.  I moved the file to /home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials as you suggested.  I also used System.IO.StreamReader to read the file and dump the output to verify it's correct.  It is correct.  I also dumped the App.Config Amazon parameters to console.  Those are also correct.  The error is the same no matter what I do.